# Spring security: j_spring_security_check page not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to use Spring Security but when I use form login (with or without correct username/password), I get a 404 error to: http://localhost/HomeAutomation/j_spring_security_check.

Here my files:

SecurityConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
      auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("greg").password("123").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {    
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/home/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
            .and()
                .formLogin().permitAll().loginPage("/index").failureUrl("/index?loginError=1")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home", true).successHandler(new LoginSuccessHandler())
                .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")        
            .and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/index?logout=1")
            .and()
                .csrf();
    }
}
```

SpringMvcInitializer.java

```
public class SpringMvcInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}
```

SpringSecurityInitializer.java

```
public class SpringSecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer{
    //nothing to do
}
```

index.jsp:

```
    <c:if test="${not empty loginError}">
        <div class="errorMsg">${loginError}</div>
    </c:if>

    <form name='loginForm' action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />" method='post'>...</form>
```

Have you any idea why this doesn't work ?

Sorry for my english.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Security's Java Configuration defaults to different URLs that the XML configuration. That means since you specified:

```
http
    .formLogin()
        .permitAll()
        .loginPage("/index")
        .failureUrl("/index?loginError=1")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/home", true)
        .successHandler(new LoginSuccessHandler())
        .usernameParameter("username")
        .passwordParameter("password")
```

Spring Security will redirect using a GET /index to request your log in page (the same value as your loginPage attribute). Spring Security will monitor POST /index for the username and password to be submitted (on the HTTP parameters username and password).

If you want to change this, you can use:

```
http
    .formLogin()

        // MODIFY HERE
        .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")

        .permitAll()
        .loginPage("/index")
        .failureUrl("/index?loginError=1")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/home", true)
        .successHandler(new LoginSuccessHandler())
        .usernameParameter("username")
        .passwordParameter("password")
```

**Additional notes**:

- It makes the Java Configuration much easier to read if you follow a few conventions on formatting. See https://spring.io/blog/2013/07/11/spring-security-java-config-preview-readability/
- You are specifying a number of properties that are the same as the defaults. For example, you do not need the usernameParameter, passwordParameter, csrf, etc

Comment: Not sure why this was not accepted, this is the correct answer. I did not realize that you need to use the same url with a POST when submitting. Thnks!